# Redis service won't start on windows

Tags: windows-7, redis, windows-services

when I try and start redis service I keep getting this error:

"The Redis service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs".

[image]

The only thing that works is restarting my computer, then the redis service is running on startup.
Is there any configuration I need to set up in order for it to work better?
I installed redis using the .msi, version 2.8.2104.

All help would be very appreciated! Thanks

Comment: When checking the event viewer in in windows i discoverd it complained about not having disk space, similar error other have had. The solution was to set the `maxheap` setting in the conf file. I set it to 2gb and it started working fine!

Answer (score 3):

Right click in the service in Window Services and go to Properties. Then go to Log On tab and select Local System account. Click on Ok button and start the service.

Answer (score 1):

For those that may have a similar problem (like we did), I found another solution.

The machine we're running on (TEST) only had `7GB` of free space on the drive. But we have `16GB` of RAM.  In our `redis.windows.conf` file, there is a setting called `maxheap` that was NOT set.

According to the documentation on `maxheap`:

```
# The maxheap flag controls the maximum size of this memory mapped file,
# as well as the total usable space for the Redis heap. Running Redis
# without either maxheap or maxmemory will result in a memory mapped file 
# being created that is equal to the size of physical memory. During 
# fork() operations the total page file commit will max out at around:
#
#    (size of physical memory) + (2 * size of maxheap)
#
# For instance, on a machine with 8GB of physical RAM, the max page file 
# commit with the default maxheap size will be (8)+(2*8) GB , or 24GB. The
# default page file sizing of Windows will allow for this without having 
# to reconfigure the system. Larger heap sizes are possible, but the maximum
# page file size will have to be increased accordingly.
# 
# The Redis heap must be larger than the value specified by the maxmemory 
# flag, as the heap allocator has its own memory requirements and 
# fragmentation of the heap is inevitable. If only the maxmemory flag is 
# specified, maxheap will be set at 1.5*maxmemory. If the maxheap flag is 
# specified along with maxmemory, the maxheap flag will be automatically 
# increased if it is smaller than 1.5*maxmemory. 
#  
# maxheap <bytes>
```

So I set it to a reasonable value and the service started right up.

Comment: I am encountering the same problem i.e. Redis service is not starting, even another service is not stopping and there is no file names `redis.windows.conf`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @bjan the `redis.windows.conf` file was in the root folder of `Redis`.  However, I admit that I didn't install Redis on that server so someone else may have manually created the file.  I believe all you need are the 5 `exe` files and that one config.  You should be able to find an example config file online.

Comment: i was trying to install multiple instances of Redis (version by MSOpenTech) but i failed, then i used an older version.

Answer (score 0):

I found a read-write error on configuration (ini)
Please check out all the files and directory specified on the INI.